# Почему дублируются css файлы

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, битрикс

Всем привет, в режиме разработки можно наблюдать такую картину

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это один css файл, который мы подключаем в  Но мне кажется он не должен дублироваться. Возможно именно поэтому низкая производительность на мобильной версии.
Как это исправить или в этом нет ничего критического? Сайт написан в битрикс

Comment: Возможно ключевое тут "в режиме разработки"... Если файл не обновлять - то и изменений не увидишь.

Comment: Нет тут имеется в виду в режиме разработчика когда на f12 нажимаем и можем смотреть элементы

Comment: Тогда смотри почему там меняется "концовка" УРЛ, т.к. это именно она вызывает каждое чтение стилей...

Comment: Есть мнение, быть может ошибочное, что всё дело в кешировании файлов.

Comment: Это разные файлы. У каждого компонента на странице есть свой файл style.css.